# If an entire orbit was a single ring shaped "planet" what would the view be like?

Tags: space, atmosphere

## The setup

Let us start by imagining a solar system. It is exactly the same as ours with a slight difference. There is no Earth. Where Earth should be is a cylinder with a radius exactly the same as Earth's. This cylinder has been somewhat distorted into a curve. Each end runs the length of approximately the Earth's orbit until they meet making it a ring. A ring with a mean cross-section radius equal to that of our planet Earth. This ring stays always well within the goldilocks zone.

For all the problems this might pose let us assume that sufficiently advanced science is involved. Let us assume everything is fine, the ring spins "slowly", that there is a standard atmosphere, and that standing anywhere on said ring is experientially the same as standing somewhere on Earth with the obvious exception of the view.

## The questions

How much of the Earth orbit sized ring would be visible to a casual observer? If we assume that the "top" in our classical view of the orbital plane is 12 O'Clock, what might a person see while standing and looking up, down, left, right, and behind at each of 12, 3, 6, and 9 O'Clocks?

I imagine that the outside of the curve (9 O'clock) would be very much similar to Earth at night - it is the rest that puzzles me.

How would the view change if there was no atmosphere and our observer was in a spacesuit or some other sufficiently advanced science?

Comment: Are you familiar with David Niven's [Ringworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringworld) series?  The main setting of these stories share a lot of features with your creation and predate you by five decades.  In fact, [this piece of ringworld fan-art](https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/hostedimages/1448885392i/17202572._SX540_.jpg) does a good job answering a few of your questions.

Comment: Your coordinate system is a bit confusing to me. When you say "top", do you mean that 12 o'clock is pointing at the sun? (Keep in mind, since your ringworld doesn't revolve around its axis or have an orbital inclination, the sun is always directly overhead no matter where you are.)

Comment: @HenryTaylor: *Larry* Niven?

Comment: @JohnDallman, right you are!  Can't believe I got that wrong.  I even looked up links and found appropriate art, all without noticing that I'd gotten the authors name wrong.    Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Interesting question. What do you mean by "spins", does it rotate around the star (akin to orbiting) or does it rotate around what would be the "centre of the earth" ? 

(Also i think the shape of the planet it a called a torus)

Comment: A ring around the sun at Earth distance with a surface area equal to Earth?   That is going to be a very small area in any particular point along the ring.

Comment: Pretty sure night is 6 o'clock not 9. 9 and 3 will be dusk and dawn.

Comment: @HenryTaylor that artwork seems awfully (several orders of magnitude) out of scale - remember that the width of the ring is on the order of *1 million* km.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík, agreed.  I found it valuable in its representation of the upward sloping horizon, not necessarily its accuracy of scale.  A more accurate rendering would start in a much wider perspective-point space and see the horizon narrowing much more quickly, possibly focusing down into a single white line at extreme distance before any upward curvature become visible. (which wouldn't be a very useful image, conceptually speaking).  Thanks for keeping me honest!

Comment: If your world is a hollow cylinder which spins around its axis to provide similated gravity on the inside surface, and is only 1,000 miles long, fine.   But how can a cylinder looped around a star with the 2 ends meeting rotate as a unit?

Answer (score 3):

## This is *a* ringworld, not *the* "Ringworld"

Like its famous counterpart, this planet is a suspension bridge without endpoints, and its orbit is unstable (unless thrusters are added, and *not* removed later) because the sun's pull on the near part overbalances the pull on the far side.

Unlike its famous counterpart, it doesn't require a neutrino-translucent unobtainium to generate false gravity from centrifugal force under high tension.  It doesn't have shadow squares to make false day and night.  Also, I trust you're not going to rashly insert a creationist backstory that casts a huge shadow over all the fun biological subplots you want.

One major issue is the budget.  We should balance the cylinder by spinning it at just the right speed so centrifugal force counters orbital gravity from the Sun ... and perhaps another source.  Using natural gravity, you need to then have mass "under" every point on the cylinder.  That means a cylinder, I dunno, maybe half the radius of Earth?  Someone should do an integral, but I'm feeling lazy.  Earth's mass is 6E24 kg; let's say that is down to 1/4, roughly 1.5E24 kg, for every 12000-km segment of the ring; let's make it an even 1E17 kg/m.  The ring is as long as Earth's orbit, namely 2 pi AU = 9.5E8 km, say 1E12m.  We have very roughly 1E29 kg of material.  A solar mass is 2E30 kg, so incredibly, this object is *not* even as heavy as the Sun, which weighs as much as 333,000 Earths.  I check this and an AU is only 11741 Earths long, so yes.  Who knew?  Get out your Mister Transmute and the star will scarcely notice the 5% rampant aliens tax.

So now that I'm convinced it's not a black *hole* or something, let's take a look up.  Niven called his view from the Sun side "the Arch", and this will look like a more proper Saint Louis arch.  The sun will always reflect best from right in the middle, though never straight on of course, and the edges will trail off to darkness.  At the terminator, the horizon is absolutely flat, unless there are high mountains like the one you'll need to see it from.  Maybe you can see a trace of a bright arc curving toward the Sun, with darkness blocking the stars to the other side, but I doubt it.  On the far side, it will be like Earthly night with all traces of odd concealed under the horizon, that is apart from the gale winds and glaciers of a tidally locked planet...

Unless ... well, we have *advanced technology*, right?  Let's put some joints in this baby and spin it up!  Every few hundred feet or every few hundred miles or every few hundred continents we'll have rifts that open up at night and close in the day.  That's to allow cylindrical segments to spin freely.  Now, this is bound to pit some kind of precessive force against the *other* motion we want, the revolution that keeps the Sun's gravity low, and thinking it through makes my head hurt.  Anyone else have trouble with gyroscope problems?  But I'm thinking if you are willing to apply some improbable torques here and there, some strong compressive forces that are managed by keeping everything exquisitely balanced on end all the way around the orbit, and have a lower gravity by day than at night, maybe misalign the center with the sun a little, you might be able to somehow get this thing to give you a day/night cycle.  Probably some spoil sport will tell me no can do no matter how advanced the tech (even if not, I doubt they'll tell me *how*) but it seems worth a sortie.

Comment: On the other hand, it would be ripe for subverting the creationist dogma. Sounds wobbly, wobbly world made by a wobbly god who left advanced looking tech around to tempt the minds of the faithful away from the wobbly path.

Comment: I think you might not even need joints.  The amount of motion along the ~600 million mile circumference  might approximate the movement of plate tectonics.  (Haven't done the math, though.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming your would forms the system where the ring encloses the star, show in the image below, I'm also ignoring the behaviour of gravity. Also assuming all observers are within ~50km of the surface.

[image]

Now you said that the shape of the planet is a [torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus) where the minor radius (the cross sectional radius) is equal to the radius of the earth, ie  $r_e=6.4\times10^{6} m$ (6.4 million metres). And the major radius (the radius of the ring) is the radius of the earths orbit, ie $r_o=1.5\times10^{11} m$ (150 billion metres). Now to describe how far around the cross sectional circle we are, I'm going to use the clock type coordinates used in you question.

[image]

Since the apparent size of objects changes with how far away they are, it is important to define an important quantity called the [angular distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_distance). It is defined as the angle between 2 sightlines, instead of metres or feed it is measured in degrees or radians. The angular size of [the moon](https://lco.global/spacebook/sky/using-angles-describe-positions-and-apparent-sizes-objects/) is about $\frac{1}{2}$°, a finger at arms length is about $1$°.

Now to get a feel for the dimensions of the planet we can make a mental model of it, to convert it to a more understandable scale. So if we consider the minor radius to be about as [thick as a hair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair%27s_breadth) (~$10^4m$) then the major radius of the ring would be about 10 metres.

This shows that the ring curves slightly compared to the radius of the planet eg the earth curves faster than this ring. Meaning that at 3 O'clock, the part of surface that is as far away as the moon ($3.5 \times 10^8m$) is only $0.00015$° above the horizon, ie the surface looks flat at least for a local radius ~$1000km$.

Now to look at how wide the planet looks in the sky, (to simplify calculations I'm modelling the planet as a section of a cylinder, which is a good approximation except for near the horizon). Now it is important to know that the [human eye can only see things](https://plus.maths.org/content/what-can-we-see) that are about $0.02$° wide. From this we can workout how far above the horizon the planet appears to be, before it is smaller than the eye can see.

It works out to be about 1° above the horizon, so it you hold out you thumb, at your arms length, it would cover all the visible part of the ring.

In summary; for all part of the ring, it would appear to be a "flat" surface with barely any of the ring being visible.

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken what you're describing is a [toroidal planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_planet) with a surface rotation that creates a day/night cycle. According to Larry Niven's *[Bigger Than Worlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigger_Than_Worlds)* you can build such an object, he calls it "Cosmic Macaroni" (it's inside out to your description but with [enough science](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AlienSpaceBats) anything is possible.

Because of the shape of the structure you're not going to see much of the rest of the place if it's a living world; at night (6 o'clock) you're facing away from the rest of the ring and all you see is the universe around you and during the day (12 o'clock) sunlight is going to wash out most of the sky, the world will look like a flat plain that eventually disappears into distance haze. There may be some visible features in the sky where other parts of the torus have a high [albedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albedo) and shine like the midday moon making them visible across a chord of the circle. At dawn and dusk (3 and 9 o'clock) the view is similar to that during the day but the curvature of the world becomes increasingly visible as the [terminator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_(solar)) approaches and as the light levels drop the brighter areas of the torus become more visible.

With a thinner atmosphere, or none at all, you'll get the "arch of heaven" effect that Niven describes in the night sky in *[Ringworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringworld)* where the world looks like a flat plain disappearing into the distance and then a parabolic arch appears to rise from each end of the area you see during the day. The night doesn't change and the dusk and dawn views are simply crisper without atmospheric distortion.

Comment: You can easily see Venus (and sometimes Mercury) from Earth at dawn & dusk, so you should likewise be able to see all of an Earth-diameter ring.  But it would basically be a bright line, rather than a Ringworld-like arch.

Comment: @jamesqf As single bright points if you know what you're looking for and because both of them are relatively bright objects, (they have high albedo) a world as dark as mercury but otherwise identical to Venus for size and location wouldn't be nearly as visible. Some parts of the ring will be visible even in the middle of the day but some parts will be much harder to spot, especially large bodies of water.

Comment: Though Mercury is difficult to spot, Venus is pretty well impossible to miss, at least if you live where there are clear skies and little light pollution.  It's the brightest thing in the morning/evening sky.  While Earth's albedo is only about half that of Venus, it's still twice that of Mars (easily-visible at times).  Both Earth & Venus are visible from Mars: https://www.space.com/mars-rover-curiosity-earth-venus-photo.html

Comment: @jamesqf Even knowing exactly where they should be it can be pretty hit and miss here, they're especially hard to spot when the star band of Milky Way is behind them. Mars is easier in the morning but Saturn can be easier to spot than Venus.

Comment: Where's here?  It's definitely not the case where I live (east side of the Sierra Nevada), nor anywhere else I can recall.  The Milky Way wouldn't be a factor with Venus, since it generally becomes visible in early twilight, while the sky is still light enough to wash out all but the few brightest stars.

Comment: @jamesqf In NZ Venus is very hit or miss in the evening, (I've never tried to spot it in the morning) Mars is very easy to spot just before dawn though. I don't know if that's because there are very few places without major light pollution, the fact that the Milky Way is far more intense in the southern hemisphere or purely a matter of latitude.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a frame challenge.

If your world is a hollow cylinder which spins around its axis to provide similated gravity on the inside surface, and is only 1,000 kilometers long, fine.   But how can a cylinder looped around a star with the 2 ends meeting rotate as a unit?

If the cylindral world is about 936 million kilometers long and straight, it can rotate as a solid unit to simulate gravity on the inside. But if you fold that clynder into a closed loop around the star with a radius of I AU or 149 million kilometers, and the ends attached, it will seem to be rotating in opposite directions on opposite sides of the star, which should break it apart.

Unless someone can prove that the stress would not be too great, it seems impossible for the structure to rotate as a unit.

Therefore it has to rotate as a bunch of separate units.  It has to be a bunch of seperate cylinders, each cylinder enclosed at both ends, with airlock connections at the axises of each cylinder.  And each of the cylinders would have to be lined up slightly differently than the cylinders at each of its ends, so that the set of cylinders has a curve around the star.

If the inside of the cylinders has a surface gravity of 1 Earth gravity, the atmopsheres in side will be thickest at ground livel on teh inside walls of the cylinders.  Teh scale height of Earth's atmosphere is the height in which atmospheric density decreases by 2.718.  It is about 8.5 kilometers.

So at 8.5 kilometers the density will be 0.3679 that at the ground, at 17 kilometers the density will be 0.1353, at 25.5 kilometers 0.0497, at 34 kilometers 0.0550, at 42.5 kilometers  0.0202, 51 kilometers 0.0074, 59.5 kilometers 0.0027, at 68 kilometers 0.0010, at 76.5 kilometers 0.003, at 85 kilometers 0.000136.

At 93.5 kilometers the density will be 0.00005 that at the ground, at 100 kilometers 0.0000183 that at the ground.  And 100 kilometers is the height of hte Karmen line in Earth, the line between Earth's atmosphere and outer space as far as aeronautics is ocncered.

Since the cylinders have radii of 6,371 kilometers, someone on the ground would need a space ship, and not an aircraft, to travel up to the center axis of thei r cylinder.

Earth's atmosphere at shea leve scatters light, making it look blue in the daylight.  Objects like distant mountains seen though tens or hundreds of kilometers of Earth's atmosphere are very faded and blurry due to the scattering of sunlight by the air in the line of sight.

So as long as someone is more than about a hundred to a thousand kilometers, depending on atmospheric conditions at the time, from one of hte end walls of their cylinder, that end wall should be invisible, ad least at ground level.

Looking upwards at a high angle, they may be able to see the center part of the end wall floating in the sky.

But if each cylinder is many times as long as its diameter of about 12,742 kilometers, the end of the cylyder would be at a very low angle seen from the surface.

I expect that the ends of  each cylder would be invisible from the inside surface at distances of about 1100 to 1,000 times the diameter, or about 1,274,200 to 12,742,000 kilometers.  So if each cylinder had something which kept people in the inside surface from getting that close to each end, the ends would be totally invisible to the people inside.  That sometihing could be a cliff going up or down, or the shore of a vast ocean or impassible swamp, or something.

So if the middle regions of the inside surface where people live and can travel are at least as long as the combined two unrachable ends, they would total at least to 2,548,400 to 25,484,000 kilometers.

But the separate cylinders should be should be as short as possible so that the chain of linked cylinders should be a close to acircle around the star as spossible, and so that the angles between adjacent cylinders be as close to straight lines as possible.

So either the cylinders should be only long enough that people inside cannot see any part of the end walls, or else you will have to accept that people can see the end walls.

Where will the light come from in the Cylinders?

My guess is that it will come from artificial "suns" at the center axes of each cylinder.  Perhps the artificial sun will move along the center axis from one end to the other end to similatethe movement of a natural sun on a planet.  It will shut off at "night" and then move back to the end it started from and turn back on at "dawn".

And if the cylinder is long enough it might have mulitiple suns,  Perhaps the inner surface wiould be divided into separate habitable areas by artificial "mountains", tall enough that the people in each second would only see one "sun".

Natural starlight could not come from giant windows, because the inside surfaces of the cylinders would be the ground.  Presumable the ground would be covered with soil, vegation, buildings, and bodies water, and even water is not transparent for long distances.

Maybe there could be giant windows in the end walls of the cylinders.  But if the end walls of adjacent cylinders almost touch, very light from the star will get in the windows, which wuld be aligned almost parallel to the direction of light from the star anyway.

The inhabited cylinders could be attached by long and much narrower cylinders to provide more space and less shadow between the inhabited cylinders so more light could reach any windows in the end walls.  But that would reduce the total inhabited space in the cylinders.

So I believe that as the cylinders spin, solar panels on the outside might convert the light of the star into eletricity to power artifical internal light sources.  Or maybe all the power for the artificial suns would come from fusion power generators.

So basically the inhabitants of the cylinders would not have any natural views of astronomical bodies or of the ring of cylinders.

The best place to put windows would be in sides of the cylinders, and since the inner surfaces of the sides would be the ground inside, they would have to be opaque.  And windows in the ends of the cylinders would be shadowed and admit little light and have very narrow views of the sky.

So people on the inner surface would see objects on the flat appearing inner surface around them which woud appear not only smaller abut also dimmer and vaguer with distance, until at the light of visibility there would just be a blur.

And looking upwards though less dense air they would see dimly the distant parts of the cylinder which enclosed them.

So they would imagine that they lived on a flat surface which floated in air and was surrounded by a vast enclosure shaped like a cylinder or a sphere.  That is what little children would deduce from what they saw.  And depending on what the inhabitants knew, that might be what older children and adults also believed.

And any astronomical objects which they say far above them would actually be an artificial "sun", and possibly also artificial "moon", "planets", and "stars".